# Include text inside PHP and hide it if no values

Tags: php

I have this piece of code:

```
<h4>Size: <?php the_field('size'); ?></h4>
<h4>Reference: <?php the_field('reference'); ?></h4>
```

If there are no values for `size` and `reference`, the texts 'Size' and 'Reference' are displayed. So I would like to add the texts "Size" and "Reference" inside the PHP function, and if there are no values on `size` and `reference` then "Size" and "Reference" are not displayed.

Sorry, I know it's a basic thing but I am just starting with PHP! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need an if/else statement inside your PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
<?php
if ($size = the_field('size')) {
    echo "<h4>Size: $size</h4>";
}
if ($reference = the_field('reference')) {
    echo "<h4>Reference: $reference</h4>";
}
?>
```

Another way:

```
<?php if ($size = the_field('size')):?>
    <h4>Size: <?=$size?></h4>
<?php endif?>
<?php if ($reference = the_field('reference')):?>
    <h4>Reference: <?=$reference?></h4>
<?php endif?>
```

or if you have short open tags enabled:

```
<?if ($size = the_field('size')):?>
    <h4>Size: <?=$size?></h4>
<?endif?>
<?if ($reference = the_field('reference')):?>
    <h4>Reference: <?=$reference?></h4>
<?endif?>
```

All of the above solutions consider 0 and "0" as having no value and so nothing is shown. If you need to show values of 0 you need to do this:

```
if (($size = (string)the_field('size'))!=="") {
    echo "<h4>Size: $size</h4>";
}
if (($reference = (string)the_field('reference'))!=="") {
    echo "<h4>Reference: $reference</h4>";
}
```

This will cast 0 to a string and become "0" which when compared to an empty string is not equal. While false and null if cast to a string become an empty string.

Comment: Much appreciated! Examples 1 and 2 fit my needs, however, the HTML does not work. Having `size` as test and `reference` as 1234 the result is test1234. It seems that the <h4> tags do not work, because it's displayed as something like ```<p>test1234</p>``` instead of ```<h4>test</h4> <h4>1234</h4>```

Comment: Try adding <style>h4{display:block !important}</style>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your "***no values***" means any value that's treated as falsy (`""`, `null`, `0`, `false`, `[]`, etc.), then you can do a simple truthy `if` condition or ternary (`<truthy> ? <true> : <false>`). You can also move the variable assignments up and grouped so you can have a more organized, cleaner, and easier-to-read code, eg,

```
<?php
...
$size = the_field('size');
$size = $size ? htmlentities($size) : 'Size';
$reference = the_field('reference');
$reference = $reference ? htmlentities($reference) : 'Reference';
...
?>
...
    <h4>Size: <?php echo $size; ?></h4>
    <h4>Reference: <?php echo $reference; ?></h4>
...
```